# What is setSize in ng-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to study API (I also looked up the meaning of that also and isn't it a small area on a page that are programmed to function in what it's coded for (for example, a box in which you set the alarm and have it ring at certain time, correct?)) at https://www.barkbox.com/subscribe/size.

I know that it's in Angular JS and I even study Angular UI router. I know that you can program the links to go to another page without reloading the page and this is similar to what I was looking for. For example, `ui-sref="home"` will call the code from home.html. Also, in ngRoute method, you use `a href="#about"` to call the code from about.html. But I don't see both in that Barkbox app at this link I provided.

The only clue to which I think would cause this barkbox app to work is `ng-click="setSize('squee')"`. I think what it did was to set the size of the box and link the whole box to another page and somehow use this code or something similar:

```
// app.js
var routerApp = angular.module('dogApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
        })

        // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
        .state('about', {
            // we'll get to this in a bit       
        });

});
```

I really learned much from studying https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router and https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating. But I have yet to study more at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.

Still, I'm trying to understand setSize function as well ng-click as in how they can link to another page. I tried to look it up but couldn't find info on that and its connection to ng-click or something like that.... Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

---------------Update----------------------
Okay, I made the code. You can see it at http://hamzakhan.name/dev/eric/options/dogsubscription.html#/dogs

html code is

```
<div class="optionwrapper size">
                <div class="option" ng-click="setSize('one')">
                    <div class="numberimage1"></div>
                    <div class="numbercontent">
                        <div class="numbertitle">One</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon-chevron-right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="optionwrapper size">
                <div class="option" ng-click="setSize('two')">
                    <div class="numberimage2"></div>
                    <div class="numbercontent">
                        <div class="numbertitle">Two</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon-chevron-right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and javascript code is

```
angular.module('dogApp', ['ui.router'])

// configuring our routes 
// =============================================================================
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

     $stateProvider

        // route to show our basic form (/form)
        .state('dogs', {
            url: '/dogs',
            templateUrl: 'dogs.html',
            controller: 'dogController'
        })

        // nested states 
        // each of these sections will have their own view


    // catch all route
    // send users to the form page 
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dogs');

})

// our controller for the form
// =============================================================================
.controller('dogController', function($scope) {

    // we will store all of our form data in this object
    $scope.dogData = {};

    // url will be nested (/dogs-oneage)
        $scope.setSize = function(one) {
             //url: '/oneage',
            templateUrl: 'dogs-oneage.html'
        }
        // url will be nested (/dogs-twoage)
        $scope.setSize = function(two) {
             //url: '/twoage',
            templateUrl: 'dogs-twoage.html'
        }
        // url will be nested (/dogs-threeage)
        $scope.setSize = function(three) {
             //url: '/threeage',
            templateUrl: 'dogs-threeage.html'
        }
        // url will be nested (/dogs-fourage)
        $scope.setSize = function(four) {
             //url: '/fourage',
            templateUrl: 'dogs-fourage.html'
        }
        // url will be nested (/dogs-fiveage)
        $scope.setSize = function(five) {
             //url: '/fiveage',
            templateUrl: 'dogs-fiveage.html'
        }

    // function to process the form
    $scope.processForm = function() {
        alert('Congratulations! You have finished the first part! Please complete the second part to finish registering.');
    };

});
```

but no matter what, I couldn't get the boxes to link to another page.... :(

Answer (score 1):

this is the name of the function in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly ng-click is: 'when you click here, this function will be called'.
So when you click on the `<div>` or `<a>` the function setSize() will becalled. 'squee' is the parameter passed to the function.
What the function does is written in the controller that is instantiated for the specific page/part of the page. You should look for a piece of code similar to: `$scope.setSize = function(param) {}`

**Answer to your updated code:**

You can add $location in your controller. An example would look like this:

```
routerApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/one', {
            templateUrl: '<*the complete link to your html file*>'
        })
         .when('/two', {
            templateUrl: '<*the complete link to your html file*>'
        })
        .otherwise({
             redirectTo: '/home',
            templateUrl: '<*the complete link to your html file*>'
        });
 }])
.controller('dogController',['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.goTo = function(url) {
        $location.path(url);
    }
}
```

And then your HTML:

```
<div class="optionwrapper size">
            <div class="option" ng-click="goTo('/one')">
                <div class="numberimage1"></div>
                <div class="numbercontent">
                    <div class="numbertitle">One</div>
                </div>
                <div class="icon-chevron-right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="optionwrapper size">
            <div class="option" ng-click="goTo('/two')">
                <div class="numberimage2"></div>
                <div class="numbercontent">
                    <div class="numbertitle">Two</div>
                </div>
                <div class="icon-chevron-right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What happens here: you tell your app that when the url matches ".com/one" it will open template one. Your div now has `ng-click=goTo('/one')`, and then with `$location.path` it will direct to the url ".com/one".

The setSize() method you wanted to use from the tutorial is a name you can change to whatever you want. In the tutorial it was probably called setSize because it adjusted the size of something. Here I renamed it to goTo() because you want to go to a certain url.
With this code I provided you should be able to manage and get it working now :-) Good luck!

Comment: So basically, I have to write a code. Something like this:
`var dogApp = angular.module('dogApp', ['ui.router']);

dogApp.config(function() {

$scope.setSize = function(squee) {
 templateUrl: ‘/squee’,
}

$scope.setSize = function(yip) {
 templateUrl: ‘/yip’,
}

$scope.setSize = function(arf) {
 templateUrl: ‘/arf’,
}

$scope.setSize = function(woof) {
 templateUrl: ‘/woof’,
}

});`

right?

Comment: No this isn't correct, since the parameter you are changing will not change the value that is passed to the parameter. Meaning: if your function is: $scope.foo = function (bar) {} and you call that function like: $scope.foo('example') would make the value of your parameter bar: 'example'. if you call it like: $scope.foo('example123'), would make the value of your parameter bar: 'example123'. So in other words, instead of changing the name of the parameter you should be changing the value passed to your parameter.

Comment: Also, to me it seems like the function setSize is used to, as the name states, set the size of something. The way you are trying to implement it now is that the function setSize redirects to certain template url's. basicly if you want to set routes, it should look like the example you gave. Based on the state a certain url /template is opened.

Comment: I don't understand the first part but I kinda understand the second part. I'm writing my code based on https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router. I will post the link with my code soon...

Comment: Hey, I updated the question with the code in question. Looking forward to your feedback. You are the greatest!

Comment: Updated my answer to your question. If this helps you getting where you want to go, please mark it as accepted answer :-)

Comment: There are some grammar errors in this code you updated.. I tried to correct the grammar errors but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Okay, I think I fixed the grammar errors but now http://hamzakhan.name/dev/eric/options/dogsubscription.html isn't responding....

Comment: there are no grammar errors in the app config and controller, and i copied the html from yours and only changed to ng-click :-)

Comment: with <*the complete link to your html file*> i mean the path to it in your app, for example '/Scripts/partials/dogs-oneage.html'